# Is it possible to change the color of the highlighted text in UWP XAML?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml, uwp-xaml

By setting a "SelectionHighlightColor" we can set the color of highlight but I wish to change the font color of text which is being highlighted. Is there any workaround to achieve this, as I couldn't find a proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I wish to change the font color of text which is being highlighted.

I'm afraid you can't custom the selection text color manually, the default `SelectionForeground` of text is white, but UWP `TextBox` has not provide property for setting font color of text. If you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with **windows feedback hub app**.